# Lexical Analyzer in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I want to read a file which in first line contains rows and in second line columns and on its basis allocate dynamic array.

After second line transition table exists in file having ASCII values of 128 characters on keyboard and last index 128 should store accepted state with some number like 101 and rejected state with -1 and then store this transition table in dynamically allocated array.

What am I doing wrong ?

This is the format of file below:

```
3 
5 
65 66 67 68 128
3 2 7 8 -1 
4 5 5 7 101
3 5 6 9 102
2 5 6 9 -1
3 6 7 8 103

#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
#include "string"


using namespace std;

int main(){
    int line=0;
    string l;
    int rows=5;
    int cols=6;
    int count=0;

    int **a=new int*[rows];// Dynamic array creation 

    for (int k=0;k<rows;k++){
        a[k]=new int[cols];
    }
    ifstream myfile ("23.txt"); // Reading file 

    if(myfile.is_open()){
        while(!myfile.eof() ){
            myfile>>l;
            cout << l;

            if ((l =="\n")||(l=="\r")){ 
                line++;
            }
            if (line ==2){
                for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){    //storing transition table in dynamically create array
                    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
                        a[i][j]=(int)l[j];
                        cout << l[j] << '\t';
                        count++;
                    } 
                }   
            }
        }
    }
    myfile.close();    //close the file
}
```

Comment: You may want to provide an example of what an input file could look like. To read a single character from an ```ifstream```, I believe you can use ```get```: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/ . I don't think ```>>``` in the code above will read just a single character which is what you are trying to do?

Comment: `while(!myfile.eof() )` Seriously where does this come from? Who keeps teaching this?

Comment: You don't need a lexical analyzer.  You must first read the number of rows and columns, *then* you can allocate the int*[] and start looping.